# grep uncommented and empty lines in linux

Tags: linux, grep

I use below command to filter the file for # and empty lines.
But, how can we grep uncommented and blank lines in linux with single grep.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat test | grep -v ^# | grep -v ^$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For simple cases, my go-to pattern for this is:

```
$ egrep '^[^#]'
```

This pattern matches lines which begin with some character OTHER than a pound sign.

If you extend the definition of 'blank' line to include a line entirely of whitespace, then the pattern fails, as it will match such a line.  The pattern also fails if you allow arbitrary whitespace before the pound sign in a comment line (as Apache, bash, and others do).

If those cases are important to you, this pattern is better:

```
$ egrep '^[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]#]'
```

For example:

```
$ cat test
# comment
  # spaces then comment
config # then comment
before empty line

after empty line
space only on next line


tab only on next line

$ egrep '^[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]#]' test
config # then comment
before empty line
after empty line
space only on next line
tab only on next line
$
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to show non-blank and non-commented lines.  You can do that with `-e` using a single `grep` command:

```
grep -v -e "^#" -e "^$" test
```

For example, if your `test` looks like this:

```
#a
uncommented line

#comment below blank line
```

output will be:

```
$ grep -v -e "^#" -e "^$" test
uncommented line
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but i am looking to do it in single go. like below(though it doesn't work)
cat test | grep -v ^[$,#]

Answer (score 1):

consider the file:

```
valid config line 1
# Comment
valid config line 2 # Comment
Blank line between

These two
One space in the line between

These two
```

If you consider the cases:

- Lines starting with #
- Blank lines

You can use `cat file | grep -v '^$\|^#'` or `cat file | grep -v '^\($\|#\)'`

And you will get something like:

```
valid config line 1
valid config line 2 # Comment
Blank line between
These two
One space in the line between

These two
```

However, I would consider also lines that start with a config line and then have an inline comment (supported in several config files), lines that are not blank but have only spaces, for this in a single command, I would use sed:

```
cat file | sed '/^\(#\|[[:space:]]*$\)/d;s/#.*//g'
```

Obtaining:

```
valid config line 1
valid config line 2 
Blank line between
These two
One space in the line between
These two
```

## Explanation

- `[[:space:]]*$` matches 0 or more spaces before the end of the line
- `^\(a\|b\)` matches lines starting with `a` or `b`, using `#` as `a` and `[[:space:]]*$` as `b` will match all lines starting with `#`, blank lines, and lines that only have spaces.
- `/match/d` deletes all the matching lines
- `;` separates sed commands
- `s/a/b/g` replaces `a` with `b` globally. Using `#.*` as `a` and an empty `b` will remove all the matching comments after a line.

Hope it helps. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat file | grep -v ^'$\|#'
```

Comment: Hi Ritesh, watch out! if you have a line like `config line # Comment` you will be taking it out with this. If all of your comments are starting with # as the first char you should use `grep -v '^$\|^#'`